# ScrollView is working in android studio but not on my smartphone

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I don't know why it is working in the IDE but when I install the apk on my device. (I have a 4000x1080 px background image in the RelativeLayout).

[image: appScreenshot]

```
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#f7f7f7"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@mipmap/space1"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Hello World !"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/level1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="455px"
        android:layout_marginTop="1300px"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think the problem is that my layout is included in an another so the onClickListener can't catch the ImageView's id...Actually this is the situation: parent includes child1 that includes myLayout with the ImageView..

Comment: I tried this in the java class, but id didn't work:                                     ImageButton level1 = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.father).findViewById(R.id.child).findViewById(R.id.imageView) ;   What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the big image in an ImageView inside the RelativeLayout and not as a background  ... and better to use **dp** dimensions units instead **px**

Answer (score 0):

just add in ScrollView and remove from RelativeLayout

```
<...

android:fillViewport="true"

 .../>
```